# Debugging illegal access to a freed memory

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am chasing a bug for few weeks now. I am working with multi threaded environment (C++, VC2010) and what I sometimes see is a crash on a new or delete.

When I look at the output I see a complain about a memory that was freed and after that was modified (`HEAP: Free Heap block 55e6128 modified at 55e619c after it was freed`). When I look at the memory at the same address (`0x55e6128`) I can see a pattern of `0xFEE`E and then `00 00 00 00` then again `FE EE`.

It looks to me as a deleted object that has a long, 4 bytes, member (or a pointer) and someone tried to set this member to zero after the object was deleted.

Any idea how to debug that?

Comment: Try [this port of Electric Fence](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) or [this one](http://code.google.com/p/electric-fence-win32/).

Comment: If you are using delete, then double delete is not a problem. If you are using free, then you should set the pointer to NULL as a good programming practice.

Comment: Try to scale down your application or at least look for a stable repro. This sort of bugs are difficult. You have a good chance not to find it at all.

Comment: These software are not for windows. The electric fence windows file is not under that link. Also I can't set the pointer to null. If I knew which pointer it is I wouldn't have this problem. Also when passing a pointer to a different thread, setting it to null will not affect the other thread. It will still try to use the old address.

Comment: I found the problem (this was a few years ago but forgot to update you). - I had 2 threads that were using the same object. Actually locking the same object. One of them finishes with the object and deletes it. And the other sets a value inside it to null - after it was deleted!!! So what I did was to use a share pointer which is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 4-byte member public? If so, this is an example of why public data members are bad and you should almost always make them private or protected (and possibly provide getters/setters).

So if it's public, I suggest making it private and adding a getter and a setter. Then set a breakpoint at the setter and keep running the application, checking every time until you see the setter called on an object that has been deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem after few weeks. There was a raw pointer to an object that was shared between 2 threads. You can't tell which thread finishes with it first so that is a problem who is responsible for the delete. One of them deleted the pointer and the other was still using it and set something to zero (hence the 4 bytes of zero that I saw on a deleted memory).
The solution was to use std::shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer with new and delete.
shared_ptr are thread safe.